# Why is my GridView not populating?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

It will populate if I set autogenerate to true. But I do not need that.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="Gridview2" Visible="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false"></asp:GridView>


protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("ConnectionString");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("sel_ResultByID_p");
            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "@pID", DbType.Int16, _id);
            ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand);

            dc = new DataColumn();
            dc.ColumnName = "FullName";
            dt.Columns.Add(dc);

            DataRow dr;
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["FullName"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["FullName"];

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            Gridview2.DataSource = ds;
            Gridview2.DataBind();
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to set your `DataSource` *before* adding the row. I've got virtually identical code (apart from that) which works. Can't see why at the moment - hence the comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 5):

You have to either set

```
AutoGenerateColumns="true"
```

or specify the gridview columns manually, like this:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="Gridview2" Visible="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FullName" HeaderText="Full Name" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

You are doing none.

**Update**

This is how you'd do it in the code behind:

```
BoundField bf = new BoundField();
bf.DataField = "YourFieldName";
bf.HeaderText = "Your Header";
Gridview2.Columns.Add(bf);
```

Comment: I need to specify the columns programmatically? How can I do this?

Comment: In the ASPX, add the `Columns` tag as the example shows. Remember, this is just an example, adapt it to your needs, since I cannot possibly know what your `sel_ResultByID_p` brings back.

Comment: I need to do this in the codebehind though. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @bronco88 Let us know if this helped you

Answer (score 0):

Is the click done asynchronously? If not then you are basically ending up doing a post but your data is gone after the click function executes and so your page is just reloaded with no data again.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn off Autogeneration of columns, you can specify which columns you want to display by using template columns

For Example.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
   DataKeyNames="EmployeeID" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1"> 
<Columns> 
 <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" />     
 <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" /> 
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="HireDate" HeaderText="HireDate" SortExpression="HireDate" /> 
</Columns> 
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Bah, sorry about original formatting, not sure what happened there.